# Capping the value

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a small script that defines the casting time for all classes in this minor project im working on however i have a few issues.

I want to place a cap on the max value however i'm getting errors!

this is the function i was referring to.

```
   void Player::ApplyRatingMod(CombatRating combatRating, int32 value, bool apply)
{
    float oldRating = m_baseRatingValue[combatRating];
    m_baseRatingValue[combatRating] += (apply ? value : -value);

    // explicit affected values
    float const multiplier = GetRatingMultiplier(combatRating);
    float const oldVal = oldRating * multiplier;
    float const newVal = m_baseRatingValue[combatRating] * multiplier;

    switch (combatRating)
    {
        case CR_HASTE_MELEE:
            ApplyAttackTimePercentMod(BASE_ATTACK, oldVal, false);
            ApplyAttackTimePercentMod(OFF_ATTACK, oldVal, false);
            ApplyAttackTimePercentMod(BASE_ATTACK, newVal, true);
            ApplyAttackTimePercentMod(OFF_ATTACK, newVal, true);
            break;
        case CR_HASTE_RANGED:
            ApplyAttackTimePercentMod(RANGED_ATTACK, oldVal, false);
            ApplyAttackTimePercentMod(RANGED_ATTACK, newVal, true);
            break;
        case CR_HASTE_SPELL:
            //ApplyCastTimePercentMod(oldVal, false);
            //ApplyCastTimePercentMod(newVal, true);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    UpdateRating(combatRating);
}

void Player::UpdateRating(CombatRating cr)
{
    int32 amount = m_baseRatingValue[cr];
    // Apply bonus from SPELL_AURA_MOD_RATING_FROM_STAT
    // stat used stored in miscValueB for this aura
    AuraEffectList const& modRatingFromStat = GetAuraEffectsByType(SPELL_AURA_MOD_RATING_FROM_STAT);
    for (AuraEffect const* aurEff : modRatingFromStat)
        if (aurEff->GetMiscValue() & (1 << cr))
            amount += int32(CalculatePct(GetStat(Stats(aurEff->GetMiscValueB())), aurEff->GetAmount()));

    if (amount < 0)
        amount = 0;
    SetUInt32Value(PLAYER_FIELD_COMBAT_RATING_1 + cr, uint32(amount));

    bool affectStats = CanModifyStats();

    switch (cr)
    {
        case CR_WEAPON_SKILL:                               // Implemented in Unit::RollMeleeOutcomeAgainst
        case CR_DEFENSE_SKILL:
            UpdateDefenseBonusesMod();
            break;
        case CR_DODGE:
            UpdateDodgePercentage();
            break;
        case CR_PARRY:
            UpdateParryPercentage();
            break;
        case CR_BLOCK:
            UpdateBlockPercentage();
            break;
        case CR_HIT_MELEE:
            UpdateMeleeHitChances();
            break;
        case CR_HIT_RANGED:
            UpdateRangedHitChances();
            break;
        case CR_HIT_SPELL:
            UpdateSpellHitChances();
            break;
        case CR_CRIT_MELEE:
            if (affectStats)
            {
                UpdateCritPercentage(BASE_ATTACK);
                UpdateCritPercentage(OFF_ATTACK);
            }
            break;
        case CR_CRIT_RANGED:
            if (affectStats)
                UpdateCritPercentage(RANGED_ATTACK);
            break;
        case CR_CRIT_SPELL:
            if (affectStats)
                UpdateAllSpellCritChances();
            break;
        case CR_HIT_TAKEN_MELEE:                            // Implemented in Unit::MeleeMissChanceCalc
        case CR_HIT_TAKEN_RANGED:
            break;
        case CR_HIT_TAKEN_SPELL:                            // Implemented in Unit::MagicSpellHitResult
            break;
        case CR_CRIT_TAKEN_MELEE:                           // Implemented in Unit::RollMeleeOutcomeAgainst (only for chance to crit)
        case CR_CRIT_TAKEN_RANGED:
            break;
        case CR_CRIT_TAKEN_SPELL:                           // Implemented in Unit::SpellCriticalBonus (only for chance to crit)
            break;
        case CR_HASTE_MELEE:                                // Implemented in Player::ApplyRatingMod
        case CR_HASTE_RANGED:
        case CR_HASTE_SPELL:
            break;
        case CR_WEAPON_SKILL_MAINHAND:                      // Implemented in Unit::RollMeleeOutcomeAgainst
        case CR_WEAPON_SKILL_OFFHAND:
        case CR_WEAPON_SKILL_RANGED:
            break;
        case CR_EXPERTISE:
            if (affectStats)
            {
                UpdateExpertise(BASE_ATTACK);
                UpdateExpertise(OFF_ATTACK);
            }
            break;
        case CR_ARMOR_PENETRATION:
            if (affectStats)
                UpdateArmorPenetration(amount);
            break;
    }
}

void Player::UpdateAllRatings()
{
    for (uint8 cr = 0; cr < MAX_COMBAT_RATING; ++cr)
        UpdateRating(CombatRating(cr));
}
```

You can notice how i want to cap the new value outcome to 32000.
Before it gets calculated to percentages!

I tried using 
if(newVal > 32000)
newVal = 32000;

Which would normally do the job i guess, but i'm stuck with an error
E0137   expression must be a modifiable lvalue

On the line newVal = 32000;

Comment: `float const newVal` - notice `const` here which means "constant". remove it or cap the value before assigning to it

Comment: do you know what `const` means? (not trying to be snarky or arrogant, but the answer to this question is essential to give you a meaningful answer imho)

Comment: "however i'm getting errors!" Please ensure that you post the errors so that people searching for the error can find the question and not raise a duplicate.

Comment: Postes the error, it was one error typed to fast, yes i know the meaning of it.

Comment: Why the edit to the code? You've taken out the only mention of 32000 which your question is based on.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `const` qualifier from `newVal`

```
float newVal = m_baseRatingValue[combatRating] * multiplier;
```

Comment: @Cyph3r__ where do you change value of Haste Rating, are you sure you set it by your `newVal` value? maybe it changes in another place or by another variable? Provide more code if it is possible

Comment: Hmmm, i wanted to private message you but i can't I'll update the question,

Comment: @Cyph3r__ May be you should pass `UpdateRating(newVal);` instead `UpdateRating(combatRating);`

Answer (score 0):

You declare `newVal` as a constant (`float const newVal = ...`), so you're not allowed to assign a new value.

Removing `const` should work for you, e.g.

```
float newVal = m_baseRatingValue[combatRating] * multiplier;

if (newVal > 32000)
    newVal = 32000;
...
```

Comment: or `float const newVal = std::min(m_baseRatingValue[combatRating] * multiplier, 32000);`